# The Following Module was built either with optimizations enabled or without debug information after frame work is changed to 4.0 from 3.5

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am using VS2010.I was changed my project and its dependent projects .Net Framework to 4.0 from 3.5.Now I could not attach the process,due to this I am not able to debug the code.
I have cleaned all the bin folders and rebuild the projects ,but still I am having following error.
[image]

Please help me to resolve this..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the question is here. The error message clearly tells you that you need to

1. Turn off (disable) optimizations
2. Turn on (enable) debug info
3. Rebuild your project so those changes take effect.

Apparently you only did step #3.

Also see [vs2010 debugging module was built without debugging information?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5420170/62576), which may provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

I also received this error, and did all the right things as described above - those have been my settings all along anyway.  I even went so far as deleting the assembly from the long C:\Users... path in the error message - it still didn't cause that message to go away.

Then I tried putting a breakpoint in the source, which should not be allowed if the module really WAS built without debug information.  And then ran the program and it stopped at the break point and I could do all the usual debugging.

So right now I'm just ignoring the message.  I could do as suggested and disable the 'Warn if no user code on launch' option as suggested in the message, but I'm not doing that until I can spend some time working out why the message comes up at all.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Uncheck this option in Visual Studio 2012.This would solve this issue]

Uncheck this option in Visual Studio 2012.This would solve this issue